# How to give Rounded corner image on mouseover with dynamic height

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to display a rounded corner image **on mouse over** on a div.. The div content is dynamic.. So I need to increase the height of the image accordingly.. How to do this..? please help

Comment: can you show us your code until now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood correctly and you want to round a divs corners on mouse over you can do it like this.

Put 4 divs with the corner images as background.

css:

```
d1, d2, d3, d4

{

   position:absolute;
   display:none;

}

d1
{

   background-image:url('cornertop.extension');
   top:0px;
   left:0px;

}
```

etc. for all

html:

```
<div id="yourid" onmouseover="roundCorners();" onmouseout="deRoundCorners()">
content
</div>
```

javascript:

```
function roundCorners()
{

   document.getElementById('d1').style.display=block;
   document.getElementById('d2').style.display=block;
   document.getElementById('d3').style.display=block;
   document.getElementById('d4').style.display=block;

}

function deRoundCorners()
{

   document.getElementById('d1').style.display="none";
   document.getElementById('d2').style.display="none";
   document.getElementById('d3').style.display="none";
   document.getElementById('d4').style.display="none";

}
```

If I understood correctly that should do it... if not... give more details pls.

Comment: That's no problem. Define a div give divs background desired image, use position relative and the rest in in the answer :)

Comment: Image is similar (not exactly) to this [link]http://t1.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcSIBcuKBOmpoGMdhtsbK0Mx6yM-VA10lojLRtv3kJ5WsL7aHFL-.. But I can not use colors..  The div content will be dynamic.. so I need to cover entire div content with the image on mouse over.. The width is fixed..

Comment: Ok... if the width is fixed do this. Crop the bottom and the top of the image (height as big as corners). Then crop 1 px height line from the middle (if it has texture or something else. if is a color just write the code :) ). Create 3 divs. On the first one put the top of the image (I suggest as background). On the middle set background-image:url('image');. On third set the bottom. This is pure css... now I understood what you asked :) I thought you wanted to make an animation. If you still can't do it send me the image and I'll send you the created html+css.